# Description on loop while PHP

Tags: php, loops, for-loop, while-loop, html-table

I want to make:

- if data is in counter 1 - 10 then the category is Very Good.
- if data is in counter 11 - 30 then the category is  Good.
- and if data is in counter > 30 then the category is Poor.

  Rank
              Name
              Score
              Date
              Category

  ```
  <?php
  include("config.php");
  $query = "SELECT s.id as id, u.id as id_user, u.nama_pegawai, s.score, s.timestamp
  FROM t_score s
  INNER JOIN pegawai u ON u.id = s.id_user
  GROUP BY s.id, u.id , u.nama_pegawai, s.score, s.timestamp
  ORDER BY s.score DESC"; 
  $result = pg_query($query);
  $counter = 0;
  while($row = pg_fetch_array($result)){   //Creates a loop to loop through results
      ?>

      <tbody>
          <tr>
              <!-- <td><?php echo $row["id"]; ?></td> -->
              <td><?php echo ++$counter; ?></td>
              <td><?php echo $row["nama_pegawai"]; ?></td>
              <td><?php echo $row["score"]; ?></td>
              <td><?php echo $row["timestamp"]; ?></td>
              <td><?php echo ++$category ; ?> </td>

              <?php 
          }
          pg_close();
          ?>
      </tr>
  </tbody>
  ```

Comment: You are expected to try to **write the code yourself**. After [**doing more research**](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/261592/1011527) if you have a problem **post what you've tried** with a **clear explanation of what isn't working** and provide [a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Read [How to Ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) a good question. Be sure to [take the tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) and read [this](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/347937/1011527).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you need to check the value of counter inside your loop using if statement or if else statement.

```
<?php

if($counter >= 30){
    $category = 'Poor';
    //your code here
}

if($counter >= 11){
    $category = 'Good';
    //your code here
}

if($counter < 11){
    $category = 'Very good';
    //your code here
}
```